# QSqlRelationalTableModel setData() not working

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

Here is a member function in a class QLSqlTableModel that derives from QSqlRelationTableModel, modified for debugging:

```
void QLSqlTableModel::setQLData(int row, int column, QVariant value){
    QModelIndex qmi = index(row, column);
    QVariant originalVal = qmi.data();
    bool isSet = setData(qmi, value);
    QVariant newVal = qmi.data();
}
```

When I run it through the debugger, my values are:

```
value = "B"
originalValue = "A"
isSet = true
newVal = "A"
```

For some reason, even though setData() is returning true, it is not actually setting the new data value.  My table implementation is:

```
QLSqlTableModel *model = new QLSqlTableModel(NULL, db);
model->setTable("tableName");
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlRelationalTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
model->generateRoleNames();
model->select();
```

Comment: Did you try calling `submitAll()` after `setData`?

Comment: @PavelStrakhov  Yes I did with no change in functionality.  As I understand it, submitAll() writes back to the database.  I'm trying to update the in-memory representation with what has been entered in a forms TextInput field.